# Webpage outputting question marks in place of unicode characters, despite character sets and collation being correct?

Tags: php, mysql, unicode

When I fetch a record from my database, where the database, the table, and the row are all set to `utf8_unicode_ci`, I recieve a question boxed in a diagonal square in place of the correct unicode character; this is despite me also setting the HTML encoding on the page with:

```
 <meta charset="utf8">
```

I have a suspicion however it is to do with MySQL/PHP though because when I `print_r` the output the question marks are still displaying while a manually entered degree symbol (the symbol I should be seeing) works fine.

This SQL query also did nothing:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

Any ideas? I've checked every end of my setup.

Comment: Are you having a font problem?  Does your font support the extended character set?

Comment: Yep, a degree symbol displays correctly when entering it manually into the webpage, but does not if I retrieve a degree symbol from the db, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`utf8_unicode_ci` is the collation, you need the character set as `utf8` as example:

```
CREATE TABLE someTable DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

As adrienne states in [their answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13035184/19679):

> make sure that all of the following are true:
>
> - The DB *connection* is using UTF-8
> - The DB *tables* are using UTF-8
> - The individual *columns* in the DB tables are using UTF-8
> - The data is actually *stored* properly in the UTF-8 encoding inside the database (often not the case if you've imported from bad sources,
>     or changed table or column collations)
> - The web page is *requesting* UTF-8
> - Apache is *serving* UTF-8

Comment: Ehhh, they changed the link, I will try to find in another source

Comment: Well, I found the article, but I have little to no terminal knowledge, so it's essentially useless. Sorry.

Comment: Just check step by step if the following as I mentioned is true

Comment: setting the character set in the DB connection worked. Thank you. However your list is very good and I will run through it all anyway.

Comment: Note that in order to fully support Unicode in MySQL, [you should use `utf8mb4` instead of what MySQL calls `utf8`](http://mths.be/utf8mb4).

Comment: Once again, if you copy the words of another, you must properly quote them, as I did above, and provide a link to the original source. Please make sure to do this yourself in the future.